# Run-time error 91 when using Type vba

Tags: vba, excel

I set a Public Type named "Info" as following

```
Public Type info
    nAtt As Integer
    nObs As Integer
    rngData As Range
End Type
```

I wrote a function aim to return 3 objects when input the range for the header (nAtt: number of attribute; nObs: number of observations; rngData: range of the corresponding core data)

```
Public Function GetDatasetInfo(rng As Range) As info

    Dim sets As info

    Dim rowRef1 As Integer
    rowRef1 = rng.Row
    Dim colRef1 As Integer
    colRef1 = rng.Column
    Dim colRef2 As Integer
    colRef2 = colRef1 + rng.Columns.Count - 1

    Dim nAtt As Integer
    nAtt = rng.Columns.Count

    Dim nObs As Integer
    Dim rngOutput As Range
    If (Cells(rowRef1 + 1, rng.Column).Value = "") Then
        nObs = 0
        Set rngOutput = rng
    Else
        nObs = rng.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown).Row - rowRef1
        Set rngOutput = Range(Cells(rowRef1 + 1, colRef1), _
                              Cells(rowRef1 + nObs, colRef2))
    End If

    With sets
        .nAtt = nAtt
        .nObs = nObs
        .rngData = rngOutput
    End With

    GetDatasetInfo = sets

End Function
```

And the following is the usage of the data:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("rng1")

    Dim v1 As info
    v1 = GetDatasetInfo(rng)
    MsgBox v1.nObs

    v1.rngData.Select

End Sub
```

The code run well without adding `.rngData = rngOutput` in the function. And the error message indicate this line has something wrong.

Please advice. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: It's an object, so you need to use `Set .rngData = rngOutput`.

Comment: Opps. Stupid mistakes. Many thanks for your clarification. I should aware the data type.